# css animate elements left to right with pause in between

Tags: css, animation, translate, keyframe

I have a row of four icons I want to animate from right to left but I want the animation to pause at some point so the each icon will be visible one after the other in a circled mask. 
I just can't figure how to pause in a middle of a keyframe. I want to know if it's possible and if it's possible without any Javascript
Thanks a lot

here is what I have now:

```
 @keyframes move {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(200%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(200%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(200%);
    -o-transform: translateX(200%);
    transform: translateX(200%);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
    -o-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
    -o-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
.icons {
  -webkit-animation: move 4s ease-in 2;
  -moz-animation: move 4s ease-in 2;
  animation: move 4s ease-in 2;
}
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-200%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-200%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-200%);
    transform: translateX(-200%);
  }
}
```

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: did you want smth like this: http://jsfiddle.net/v4yy049v/ ?

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide your HTML and clarify a little more it may be easier to understand exactly what it is you're trying to achieve.

But if you're looking to just stagger your icons you can use :nth-child pseudo selector to put a unique delay on the different icons, and then adjust your animation %'s to keep the icons positioned for your desired time.

```
.icons:nth-child(2) {
   animation-delay: 1s;
}
.icons:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.icons:last-child {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
```

---

[Here is a working example](http://codepen.io/radenB/pen/ygNgjZ) of staggering your animation using nth-child.